# Is it possible for three distinct positive integers to exist such that sum and difference of every two is a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics, square-numbers

I have been struggling with this problem for quite some time now but i haven't been able to find a solution yet.
My first approach was to try and make an Euler's Brick type form but that didn't really work.
Then i generalised it for two such numbers to get
{(x,y)}={(n²-2nm+2m²,2nm-2m²)} where n>2m.

After solving some more and making some equations I ended up with equations which represented stuff like

a-b+b+c=a+c

Just in complicated perfect square forms. And then I got stuck.
Can anyone please help me solve this problem?

Comment: You can use the fact that $n^2\equiv 0,1 \mod 4$ for all $n$ to deduce that all three must be even numbers. If you can further show that all three must be divisible by 4, you could use infinite descent to show no such triple exists.

Comment: @eyeballfrog you could have the two smaller ones be $0\text{ mod }4$ and the largest one be $1\text{ mod }4$ . That still satisfies all the modulo constraints.

Comment: @user3257842 Ah, good catch.

Comment: Brute force reveals that the largest of the numbers must exceed $10^5$. The triple $(64/80/89)$ comes close , only $64+89$ is not a perfect square.

Comment: @Peter not finding solutions up to $10^5$ is a good hunch that a solution probably doesn't exist.

Comment: @user3257842 To be honest , I think $10^5$ is far too small to draw a conclusion. Too bad that the above idea fails. It would have been a very elegant solution.

Comment: The full list of $\text{mod }4$ tuples that can generate a valid $\text{mod }4$ solution is:

$\{(0, 0, 0), (0, 0, 1), (2, 2, 2), (2, 2, 3)\}$

Comment: After repeatedly using rational parametrisation of the unit circle, you reduce to basically finding rational solutions $(q_1,q_2,q_3)\in\mathbb{Q}^3$ to (something like) $q_1^2(1-q_2^2)^2+q_2^2(1-q_1^2)^2=q_3^2$ subject to various conditions ($q_1,q_2\neq 0,\pm 1$, plus an inequality to guarantee the solutions are positive).  Not sure how helpful it is.  Being a sextic, I don't expect a lot of solutions if at all.

Comment: I looked up the eulerbrick-conjecture. The existence of an Euler-brick implies a solution of this problem. This is unfortunately open , but the so-called face-cuboids could also give a solution. I could not find the list of those face-cuboids , the ones shown in the linked paper did not do the job , but one of the others might be.

Comment: Is is virtually hopeless to prove that the given problem has no solution. Because this would also prove that there is no Euler-brick and this seems to be out of reach.

Comment: I was also trying to make it so that the problem connects to Euler's Brick but i wasn't able to do so, can you please share how you were able to make that link

Comment: Alright I tried again and was able to form the Euler's Brick. I guess I just had to give the Brick approach a little more time. If I had done that then wouldn't have posted the query. Anyway Thanks I got my answer.